# Exporting Excel in Rails 4, unable to open in Microsoft Excel but works in Libre Office

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I having trouble opening the generated/exported excel in Microsoft Office Excel.

But it works fine in Libre Office.

I tried to make a simple test as code below.

**Controller:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html   
    format.xls do 
      headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/xls'
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='Report.xls'"
    end
  end
```

**view code:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
      <Table>
        <Row>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
        </Row>
      <% 5.times do |product| %>
        <Row>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product %></Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product %></Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product %></Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product %></Data></Cell>
        </Row>
      <% end %>
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </Workbook>
```

I followed from this tutorial, [railscasts/362-exporting-csv-and-excel](https://github.com/railscasts/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

**I tried to used simple html in view, and it worked.**

**So, I think there's a problem with using XML as template.**

Please help to troubleshoot the problem.

[Here is a sample generated excel file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfik5oyn62nk450/test.xls?dl=0)

Comment: Could you attach result .xls file?

Comment: May be it will be more reliable to use [axlsx gem](https://github.com/randym/axlsx)

Comment: @MikhailMalov, Yes I migrated to axlsx gem.
But still I want to know the cause of the error.

Comment: Attach generated with error .xls please

Comment: I added link for the .xls file that cannot open in MS. Excel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[XML spredsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx) is supported by Microsoft Office Excel 2003 not by new versions

Comment: Isn't xlsx a zipped folder with xml files inside?

Comment: This Excel format, SpreadsheetML, is still supported in current versions of Excel (as of Sep 4, 2020)

Answer (score 1):

First, the extension should be `.xml`, and not `.xls`.
`.xls` is a binary format : even if your `.xls` had a correct syntax for an `.xml` file, Excel would complain at startup.

It shouldn't be `.xlsx` either. xlsx is XML based, but it is a whole zipped structure. You could do it, but you would need more complex code and rubyzip.

My advice would be to write plain `.csv` file. Easy to write, easy to read and easy to open with Excel/OpenOffice.

If you really want to write a [Microsoft Office XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) :
I opened the xls file you provided with OpenOffice. I saved it as xlsx from OpenOffice, opened it with Excel, saved it as xml (2003 version), and removed all the optional attributes. Here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="titleStyle">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="15" ss:Color="#FFFFFF"
    ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#E22828" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="dataStyle">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Applicant Data">
  <Table>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="titleStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Code No.</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="titleStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Country</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="titleStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="titleStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Email</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="titleStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="dataStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```